# Eldad and Medad Age

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

According to the Rosh's commentary on the Torah, Eldad and Medad mentioned in Numbers 11:26 were the half-brothers of Moses. The Rosh explains that during the giving of the Torah, Moses' father Amrom, divorced and remarried. Eldad and Medad were born from this second marriage.

> אלדד ומידד – אחי משה היו אלא שכשנתנה תורה ונאסרו כל העריות פירשו כלם
> שנא׳ וישמע משה את העם בוכה למשפחותיו ודרשינן על עסקי משפחות וגם עמרם
> אבי משה פירש מיוכבד דודתו שהיתה אשתו ונשא אשה אחרת והוליד ממנה אלדד
> ומידד ומצאתי שהובאו קונדריסין אל רב עמרם גאון הגולה מר׳ הלל שהיה מארץ
> ישראל אני הלל ראיתי קברי אלדד ומידד אחי אהרן מן האב ולא מן האם ויש
> אומרי׳ אלדד ומידד אלידד בן כסלון מידד הוא קמואל בן שפטן ותימא היאך
> מצי׳ למימר שהיו אחי משה והלא מצינו אלידד בן כסלון שהוא ממטה בנימין
> וקמואל בן שפטן שהוא ממטה אפרים וצ״ל דמאן דאית ליה הא לית ליה הא.

However, in verse 5, they are referred to as "elders," even though they would have been only a couple of months old. How can they be described as elders if they were just infants, as suggested by the Rosh's explanation?

Comment: “Elders” in this case means wise men - See Kiddushin 32b

Comment: Also refer to the Targum Yonason, Bamidbar 11:26 for this notion that they were half brothers of Moshe - https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jonathan_on_Numbers.11.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @שלום true but why would a six or seven month old baby be called wise?

Comment: @Dov True. Yet my question is referring to the pirush Harosh.

Comment: The Gemara says that the elders were chosen by casting lots, so it’s possible that it was like the lots that were drawn for the devision of Eretz Yisroel, which was “Al Pi Hashem”, who knew their potential to be wise

Comment: I hadn't seen this question beofre i asked similar myself - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135398/%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%93%d7%93-%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%93%d7%93-how-old-were-they.

Even if they were wise, how could they be mebers of the סנהדר'ן at this age?