# אלדד מידד how old were they?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, dor-hamidbar, behaalotcha-parsha

אלדד מידד were 2 people who received a prophecy whilst at home in their camp during the Jews' sojourn at קברת התאוה. There is debate amongst the rishonim whether they were supposed to have been memebers of the newly formed סנהדר'ן.

This encampment took place somewhere in the 2nd year out of Egypt between the 20th of Iyar and 28th of Sivan. (See Bamidbar 10 - 11 for when they left Sinai towards קברת התאוה and the spies were sent out on 29th Sivan - cannot remember the source for that).

There are varying opinions about who exactly אלדד מידד were.
ספרי and the תרגום יהונתן agree that they were half brothers of משה.

The problem is that the ספרי says that at Sinai, עמרם divorced יוכבד on account of her being his aunt which had now become an illicit relationship. He went on to marry and this marriage produced אלדד and מידד.

According to this, at the time of their prophecy, they must've been approximately 1 years old and probably twins! Whilst youngsters having that capability at such an age may be possible

1. why does the torah refer to them as אנשים
2. how could they possibly be fit for serving on the סנהדר'ן (leaving aside the fact that they were brothers and related to משה)?

Comment: Dupe of this unanswered question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135263/eldad-and-medad-age

Comment: thanks - it did not pop up as a suggestion. although I have added the question regarding the סנהדר'ן

Comment: @terryg it may also be helpful to familiarize yourself with the [jargon policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1607/2394). The overall guiding principle is "Will any English speaker who is interested in this content be able to understand what it means without additional research?" Glad to have you with us. All the best.